# How to prevent regex from validating double dots after @ character

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using the following regex in a js

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```

This validates email in subdomain (ex: `myname@google.co.in`)
Unfortunately a double dot is also validated as true, such as

```
myname@..in
myname@domain..in
```

I understand the part `@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]` is to be modified but kinda struck. What is the best way to proceed.

TIA

Comment: Your e-mail validation regex is incorrect, and it’s [hard to write correct ones](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1), so try to use something pre-built. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: Please reconsider accepted answer, the one you accepted is not doing what is required.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+)(@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}){2,}$
```

You can test it here - https://regex101.com/r/Ihj8sd/1

Comment: You regex is equivalent to ``^(.+)(@.+)(.[a-zA-Z]{2.4}){2,}$``. Escape the dot ``.``, as is it doesn't matches **only** the literal dot (it matches everything now, making the other chars in the groups redundant). Also why so much unused capturing groups? Watch the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yR2yQ5/1) As is it doesn't solve the OP problem...

Comment: This regex does not actually require a dot after `@`.

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
^([\w+-]+\.)*[\w+-]+@([\w+-]+\.)*[\w+-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$
```

I've replaced the `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with the exact equivalent `\w` in the char group.

Note that in the regex language the dot `.` is a special char that matches everything (but newlines). So to match a literal dot you need to escape it `\.`.

**Legenda**:

- `^` start of the string
- `([\w+-]+\.)*` zero or more regex words (in addiction to plus `+` and minus`-`) composed by 1 or more chars followed by a literal dot `\.`
- `[\w+-]+` regex words (plus `[+-]`) of 1 or more chars
- `@` literal char
- `([\w+-]+\.)*[\w+-]+` same sequence as above
- `\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}` literal dot followed by a sequence of lowercase or uppercase char with a length between 2 and 4 chars.
- `$` end of the string